# Total commander, сравнить папки, если не сходится выделить или дописать

Tags: totalcommander

Задача:
В левой и правой колонке в TC открыта одинаковая папка, внутри неё файлы и папки.

Необходимо сравнить размеры папок и файлов левой и правой колонки и если где-то размер не сходится дописать или как-то выделить, чтобы я в ручную потом дописал.

Общая цель: продублировать информацию с одного гугл-диска на другой.

Пробовал сделать через Air Explorer, справляется только частично.

Comment: А что копирование с заменой не работает?

Comment: Выделение - Сравнить каталоги

Comment: Меню "команды" - "синхронизировать каталоги". Файлы могут сравниваться по имени, дате изменения, содержимому. Папки сравниваются по своему содержимому (по файлам, которые в них).